# How can I add a favorite article marking system with django generic class-based view?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-2.2

I'm trying to let my users mark favorite posts that they can read later.
I've seen some solutions using FBV, but I want to make favorite markers with CBV.

How can I do it using django class-based view (DetailView) ?

## model

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    favorite = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(),  related_name='favorite', blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

## views

```py
class ArticleDetailView(ObjectViewMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article'
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        return context


def favorite_post(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
    if post.favorite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.favorite.remove(request.user)
    else:
        post.favorite.add(request.user)
    return redirect('article_detail', pk=article.pk)
```

## urls

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article_update'),
    path('<int:pk>/favorite_post/', favorite_post, name='favorite_post'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the `UpdateView` and override its `post()` method; you can use its `.get_object()` method the get the current `Article` instance.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from .models import Article

class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    http_method_names = ['post', ]
    model = Article

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if self.object.favorite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            self.object.favorite.remove(request.user)
        else:
            self.object.favorite.add(request.user)

        return redirect('article_detail', pk=self.object.pk)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:pk>/favorite_post/', MyUpdateView.as_view(), name='favorite_post'),
]
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi @Ralf , It throws 403 error when request.user is not article.author. I want this feature available for any user. Not only article author.

Comment: @TareqMonwer I don't know why my code would raise a 403. Have you added any code besides the code from my answer?

Comment: yes, I did. I thinks it's coming for migration problem. I'm facing migration problem now.  It says I have migrations to apply but migrate does not work. I've tried --fake also. Didn't work. Can you provide any solution please?

Comment: @TareqMonwer can you elaborate on what you mean by "it did not work as well" ?

Comment: Instead of redirecting to the article detail page, the post request stays at favorite_post url.